# Defining a JS function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am Working on a little Webpage, which has a .php-include hierarchy. 
Now I want to generate two relying Dropdown-Menues, where the second one is updated, after you choose an option in the first one.

I would prefer if the code for this page could stay in one file, as I want to achieve this without splitting the code.

The code looks something like this:

```
<?php
echo '<div id="dashheader">
<form action="..." method="get" enctype="text/plain">
<p id="dashheadline">Selbstkosten ermitteln</p>
..
<td><select name="lieferant" onChange="javascript:updateArtikel(this.value);" >
...
<div id="art">
    <select name="artikel">
    <option value="">Erst Lieferanten wählen</option>
    </select>
</div>';
?>
```

Now i have the Javascript which I want to be executed on a Change in the "lieferant"-Dropdown(Simple Ajax Call):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateArtikel(str) {
        ...
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("art").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","cure1.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        ...
     }
</script>
```

cure1.php is the same .php-File I generate the Output in. It also contains additional php-Code, in Case it is called with a parameter "q" (see AJAX-Call):

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    echo '<select id="art" name="artikel">';
    $abfrage = //MYSQL-Query; 
    $ergebnis = mysqli_query($con,$abfrage);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis))
    {
        echo '<option value = "'.$row->PositionsNr.'" > '.$row->Artikelbezeichnung.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Now the Question:
Is it really possible to leave this code in one File?
If not, How shall I put the code, if the "cure1.php" (my page) is loaded per "index.php?menu=10" ?

Comment: have you try to do that? or you have some errors? for my opinion it seems to be working...

Comment: Well, of course, I tried it, yet the page does nothing, if I change the content of "Lieferant"-Dropdown.

Comment: Well, despite it sounds reasonable, be aware that you are executing a query with a parameter sent by the user (str) which can potentially result in a sql injection: I would first start by sanitizing your query before executing it. Also, try to `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);`, it would be helpful to know what is the response.

Comment: The Query-Sanitizing is already implemented and will be included, after this Step works. I just wanted to have the least amount of error-sources.

Comment: To Log the response of the Server, the Javascript-Method would have to be called. 
I have put an "alert("hello")" at the start of the script-function "updateArtikel" - it is never called.

Comment: You can leave it in one file, but the code with the response for ajax request must come above all other code. And don't forget to `exit` after `echo '</select>';`.

Comment: @MichaelWerner : So the "change" event is not working? In a nutshell, you're telling us that the dropdown change is never fired, right? If it doesn't, try to bind the event manually through js: http://jsfiddle.net/y49pkegu/ or just call the function and remove "javascript:", despite doing everything in js is easier to mantain.

Comment: @briosheje - Exactly, regardless, of what I choose, the JS-Function isn't even called.

Comment: @MichaelWerner: I've updated my comment above, the problem is probably that the event is not being binded correctly, hence I recommend you to bind it manually. Also, be sure to execute your script AFTER the dom has been loaded. It will be helpful to have a clearer view of your html-js part, but as long as you can bind the change event everything should be fine.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you mean by "binding" the event. If you mean the jQuery-binding: I am not supposed to use jQ.

Comment: @MichaelWerner : You don't need jQuery to add an event listener, in the fiddle above it was done without jQuery. If by assigning the event in such a way it is still not working then the problems may either be that you are executing the script BEFORE the document has been loaded (hence it is trying to listen on a dom element that doesn't yet exists) or that you have some syntax errors or any other kind of error that stops the execution of the script. To determine if you have any error, just check your javascript console from your browser, they usually are all there.

Comment: As you already guessed, I get an Error "updateArtikel is not defined". 
This happened, after i have successfully bound an EventListener to the Dropdown

Answer (score 0):

see your hierarchy of php file carefully.
At last code should like

```
<?php 
......
//php code
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          //javascript code
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

you may also echo all html code within php tags.
This is standard, you may not restricted to do same.